# Queue city location in database language independent

Tags: database, database-design

I'm currently facing the following issue:
My database has a table of restaurants with locations (composed of Country, City, Street).

Now, any user can add a restaurant.
Now, let's say that a user clicks on <kbd>Add</kbd> and enters the following:

> 'Restaurant de Mar' in Gustastreet 7, Nueva York, Estados Unidos.

The next user clicks on the filter and selects "New York".
It should, of course, display the entry from the Spanish user as well.

I've thought about the following solutions to allow filtering on a city level:

1. Store everything in English. If a user submits or requests a location, use e.g. google's geocoder to get the English name.
   **Disadvantage:**
   No way to show the user in his own language in which country there are entries at all.
2. Store Lat/Long for every address (also needs API call for that). If a user requests entries of a city, also use an API to get the bounds of that city and search the Lat/Long points in the database for this specific boundary.
   **Advantage:**
   No need for any localization.

Is there any documented approach for this?

Comment: StackOverflow is for problems / errors / exceptions in your code.
You should try https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/
It's better suited for architectural questions.

Comment: @Korashen: Thanks, posted it on dba now. Think it fits best there. Shall I delete it here?

Comment: Well, there could be people around here who might have an answer for you. Or people will downvote your question. Or nothing will happen here. I would say, keep it until people start downvoting it.

Comment: @Korashen when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat Ah, right, now as you say it, I remembered reading this somewhere. Haven't seen it since a long time, so I kind of forgot it.
In this case, I do recommend to delete the post on SO, of course.